# How many dimensions are there according to Buddhism?

Tags: buddhist-cosmology

Humans or most of the organisms in this world can perceive three dimensions. Does buddhism explain about dimensions? If so how many are there?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Buddhism SE. We have a [Guide](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post?cb=1) and a [Resource tab](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) for new users that you might like.

Answer (score 3):

The [Sigalovada Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.ksw0.html) mention "the six directions":

> At that time a young householder named Sigalaka arose early and set out from Rajagaha with freshly washed clothes and hair.[3] With palms together held up in reverence,[4] he was paying respect towards **the six directions**:[5] that is **east, south, west, north, lower and upper**.

I take that to imply *three* dimensions.

It's not explicitly about dimensions but it casually implies in passing that there are three dimensions (perhaps as if it's the kind of thing that everyone knows and doesn't need explaining).

Modern maths (since the [late 18th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-dimensional_space#History)) has described "time" as a kind of dimension. Buddhist texts imply that time, too, can be perceived.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :) AFAIK these directions are not related to cosmology, They were said by lord buddha to give a meaning to the worshiping of directions. In it parents (East), teachers (South), wife (West), and friends and colleagues (North), Brahmins (Up) and the Servants (Down).

Comment: @Dinal24 Yes that is the subject of the sutta. I am referencing it out of context, but I thought it helped answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Space (Akasa Pannattis) and time (Kala Pannattis) are a conceptual or perception based construct (Pannattis).

Many of the population can perceive in 3D: [Stereopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereopsis). There are some who cannot perceive in 3D: [Stereoblindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereoblindness). So the dimensionality differs from person to person or how you perceive it. Buddhism looks at the world through the experience of a being than a generalised truth independent of a observer and his experience of it.

See: [Time and space: The Abhidhamma perspective, Professor K. N. Jayatilleke Memorial Lecture 2003 by Y. Karunadasa.](http://www.lankalibrary.com/Bud/time.htm). Also [The Dhamma Theory](http://www.abhidhamma.org/dhamma_theory_philosophical_corn.htm) by Y. Karunadasa which discusses Pannattis.

Comment: Or doesn't the buddhism looks at the reality rather than what people perceive? :/

Comment: Both. It it is Paramartha Dharma it is independent of the observer if it is Pannattis it is as a person perceives it or metals constructs.